Getting gtsummary table for ivreg with binary treatment
EDIT
I have found a work around (for now) to just convert the binary treatment into a true binary variable (treated = 1, untreated = 0), but it would be good to find a method that could handle factors etc.
ORIGINAL QUESTION
I'm fitting an ivreg() using the ivreg package, and it seems tbl_regression() can only handle the result if the treatment is continuous. Looking at it, it seems to be an issue with ivreg() sticking the treatment level onto the treatment name such as treatmentYes. Here's a repex.

library(ivreg)
library(gtsummary)

data("SchoolingReturns")

## This works (with warnings)

iv_continuous <- ivreg(wage ~ education | nearcollege,
                data = SchoolingReturns)

summary(iv_continuous)

tbl_regression(iv_continuous)

## This does not

iv_binary <- ivreg(wage ~ nearcollege | education,
                data = SchoolingReturns)

summary(iv_binary)

tbl_regression(iv_binary)



Is there anything I can do to work around this issue? I know stargazer etc. work, but all my other tables in the paper use gtsummary and really prefer the output it gives

For dichotomous factor variables, a workaround is to convert them to numeric and run the model again:
SchoolingReturns$nearcollege <- as.numeric(SchoolingReturns$nearcollege)

iv_binary <- ivreg(wage ~ nearcollege | education, data = SchoolingReturns)

broom::tidy(iv_binary, conf.int=TRUE)
# A tibble: 2 × 7
  term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value conf.low conf.high
  <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
1 (Intercept)   -1410.      261.     -5.40 7.04e- 8   -1922.     -899.
2 nearcollege    1182.      155.      7.62 3.34e-14     878.     1486.

tbl_regression(iv_binary)



